# 'cat': can't open file: Permission denied

Tags: command-line, permissions, filesystem, files, sysfs

I am trying to copy the whole `/` directory to some other location. When doing cp recursively, it fails on some files like:-

```
/ # ls -lrt /sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/uevent
--w-------    1 root     root          4096 Mar  7 06:29 /sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/uevent
/ #
/ # cat /sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/uevent
cat: can't open '/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/uevent': Permission denied
/ # cp /sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/uevent /tmp
cp: can't open '/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/uevent': Permission denied
```

If I create some file with only `w` permissions and try to copy/cat it, I could see no problems there. However, for some files like the one mentioned above, I am unable to copy it or to cat it even though I am trying as root user. Also, the strange thing is that the size of the above mentioned file is mentioned to be as 4096 which is similar to the one we have for directory. Is this something special file?

I guess I am missing something here and need some input to know more about such files or such behaviors. Kindly do help me out in understanding why I am not allowed to cat contents of such files.

Answer (score 10):

In a regular filesystem e.g. `ext4`, if you only have `w` permission in a file, you won't be able to read (`cat`) it, you need read (`r`) bit for that. Note that, `root` can read any file regardless of the permission bits.

Now, `/sys` is a mount point of special `sysfs` provided by Linux kernel which is actually a virtual filesystem and works differently than regular filesystems. `/sys` contains device related info of the system.

Modifying something in `/sys` would directly alter kernel's internal data structure so it depends on kernel what it would permit or deny.

For `/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ipv4/uevent`, you have only `w` bit set for owner (`root`), even if you add `r` bit for `root` (**which is a very bad idea**), while reading the file you would get I/O error because by design the kernel would not allow anyone to read the uevents for the `nf_conntrack_ipv4` module.

Comment: I tried it on one of my VM's having ext4 filesystem and I was able to cat contents of file which had only `w` flag set. Here is output: http://pastebin.com/m1aKAe0b

Comment: This is wrong: Root can read regular files regardless of read permissions. As the OP's question already explained.

Comment: @alexis Where did you find in my answer that i said root can not read a file having only write bit set?

Comment: Um, the first paragraph? You *are* answering a question about doing this as root, you know.

Comment: @alexis Here _you_ excludes root obviously, perhaps that needs to be clarified a bit ..editing..

Answer (score 4):

To avoid special file systems like `/sys` and `/proc`, you should give the following option to `cp`:

```
-x, --one-file-system
    stay on this file system
```

(quoted from [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html))

If you have several actual file systems, e.g. `/` and `/home`, you will then need to give several `cp` commands.

Be careful that you don't copy *from* and *to* the same place.  That can lead to infinite loops where you make copies of copies of copies of ...

Comment: Is it possible to copy / anywhere without the destination being inside of the source?

Comment: @Pace It would have to be to another file system. (Network fs, USB stick etc)

Comment: @Pace, with `cp -x` you are safe as long as the destination is on a different file system (logical drive).